# If one "if" is used I don't want the others to be used.

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

If I type 18 the following answers from the other ifs show up.

```js
var age = prompt("please enter your age")

var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

if (age == 18) {
  alert("welcome to our website")
}
if (age > 18) {
  alert("welcome to our website")
}
if (age < 18) {
  alert("you aren't allowed to visit this website")
  window.close()
}
if (age = letters) {
  alert("please enter a valid number")
  prompt("please enter your age")
}
```

Comment: Use `if (age == letters)`?

Comment: The title should give a _short summary_ of the problem and not be the complete question/text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you have too many tests. Since you want to do the same thing if the user is 18 or greater than 18, you can combine those two.

And since you have only two conditions and outcomes regarding age, you can turn the other `if` test into `else` branch so that only one test branch is entered.

But, you aren't testing the user input against your regular expression properly. There are a couple of ways to do it, but the simple [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method will do the trick. Even if that were the way to do the regular expression test, your last `=` would need to be `==` so that you can do a comparison, rather than an assignment.

See below:

```js
var age = prompt("please enter your age");

// First just test to see if they entered letters or not
if(testInput(age)){ 
  // Some letters were entered...
  alert("please enter a valid number");
  age = prompt("please enter your age");
  testInput(age); // test again
}

// When there are only numbers...
if (age >= 18) {
  alert("welcome to our website");
} else {
  alert("you aren't allowed to visit this website");
  window.close();
}

// This function will accept a string
function testInput(age){
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  // And return true or false based on testing the string
  // against the regular expression.
  return letters.test(age);
}
```

Comment: I've seen it thanks and im sorry for that stupid little mistakes but I really wanted it to work

Comment: @Fleming You're welcome. Please consider marking my answer as "the" answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateAge() {

  var age = prompt("please enter your age")
  // var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  // if input will be any other symbol besydes letters&digits no alerts in that case
  // \D "not digit" would be better regexp
  var notDigit = /^\D+$/;
  // you can use 'greater or equal >=' & 'less or equal <='
  if (age >= 18) {
    alert("welcome to our website")
  }
  if (age < 18) {
    alert("you aren't allowed to visit this website")
    window.close()
  } // you know regular expressions but not the functhions to work with? 
  if (age && age.match(notDigit)) {
    alert("please enter a valid number")
    validateAge()
  }
}

validateAge()
```